# Rails: Using simple_form and integrating Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build a rails app and simple_form looks to be a really useful gem. Problem is that I am using twitter bootstrap css to do the styling and the simple_form doesn't allow you to specify the layout of the html.

Can anyone tell me how I can conform the simple_form html into the format bootstrap css wants?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

*Note: This answer only applies to SimpleForm < 2.0*

Start with this in `config/initializers/simple_form.rb`:

```
SimpleForm.form_class = nil
SimpleForm.wrapper_class = 'clearfix'
SimpleForm.wrapper_error_class = 'error'
SimpleForm.error_class = 'help-inline'
```

Then there's space missing between the label element and the input, which you can add with this:

```
label {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

There's probably more, but it's a start.

Comment: Looks good only thing I would add in case of conflicts with simple_form's template:  config.form_class = nil

Comment: @jevy Thanks, added it to my answer.

Comment: Just to warn those who are working with SimpleForm v2.. some of these settings have changed and no longer exist.

Answer (score 23):

Simple form 2.0 is bootstrap-aware:

```
rails generate simple_form:install --bootstrap
```

Answer (score 5):

I recently had the same problem and tried out the combination of [bootstrap-sass](https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass) and [formtastic-bootstrap](https://github.com/mjbellantoni/formtastic-bootstrap).
It works with the exactly same code as the code for formtastic and shows even error messages as expected.

`bootstrap-sass` also works with Rails 3.1 Asset Pipeline and Rails 3.0. `formtastic-bootstrap` is tested with RSpec so I think this is a nice way to go!

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a gem to do exactly this. It's not simple_form, but it should work fine side-by-side: [twitter_bootstrap_form_for](https://github.com/stouset/twitter_bootstrap_form_for).

Comment: does this modifies scaffold generated forms as well ?

Comment: No. Scaffolding isn't meant to be pretty.

Answer (score 3):

simple_form allows for a css class (Passing in `:html => {:class => nil}` will result in only a "simple_form" class.).
n.b. This was added on 7/25/2011 so many existing downloads and documentation will not have it.  You could also wrap it in a div that specifies a style.

You can also always style an individual element with code such as

`<%= f.input :username, :label_html => { :class => 'my_class' } %>`

Answer (score 3):

Here's the full config (config/initializers/simple_form.rb):

```
SimpleForm.setup do |config|
  config.hint_class = 'help-block'
  config.error_class = 'help-inline'
  config.wrapper_class = 'clearfix'
  config.wrapper_error_class = 'error'
  config.label_text = lambda { |label, required| "#{label} #{required}" }
  config.form_class = nil
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I found this, seems working fine https://github.com/rafaelfranca/simple_form-bootstrap don't known about tight integration

Answer (score 2):

If you use SimpleForm 1.5 the authors of the gem provide you with the required configuration instructions here: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Twitter-Bootstrap-integration

Answer (score 0):

In this railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/329-more-on-twitter-bootstrap, you can see how to customize simple_form with twitter bootstrap (skip to 3:05).

**terminal :**

```
rails g simple_form:install --bootstrap
```

**model/_form.html.erb :**

```
<%= simple_form_for @product, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <fieldset>
    <legend><%= controller.action_name.capitalize %> Product</legend>

    <%= f.input :name %>
    <%= f.input :price %>

    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
      <%= link_to 'Cancel', products_path, :class => 'btn' %>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>
```