# In Rails 3, using Formtastic 2, how can I replace the built in ordered list with div's?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic, twitter-bootstrap

In my Rails 3 application I'm using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) as a frame work for developing an in house project management system. I'm using Formtastic to help me with forms since it save a lot of time and code. My problem is getting the Formtastic code to output the forms in a way that correspond with Bootstrap's conventions. I've read a few items I found on Google suggesting that I should monkey patch Formtastic, but I haven't been able to do this successfully.

How can I customize Formtastic's output to use div's around each field so I can use Bootstrap with it?

Thank you for looking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [formtastic-bootstrap](https://github.com/mjbellantoni/formtastic-bootstrap) gem.  You should be able to drop this in and it will generate HTML that will work naturally with Twitter Bootstrap.

Answer (score 7):

Well, today I tried forking formtastic and making it compatible with bootstrap...  The markup is incredibly tightly coupled to the code, so I gave up and switched to simple_form instead.  Works fine with the advice in [Rails: Using simple_form and integrating Twitter Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198109/rails-using-simple-form-and-integrating-twitter-bootstrap)

Comment: I'll leave the question unanswered since this doesn't really answer it, but I'll +1 it and probably end up go this route.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the SCSS files from the one of the [scss-twitter-bootstrap](https://github.com/teddyzetterlund/twitter-bootstrap-scss/tree/master/lib) projects, you can simply comment out or remove the include for the forms part of the CSS.

Simply copy them in to app/stylesheets (Rails 3.0) or app/assets/stylesheets and comment out:

```
// @import "forms.scss";
```

Don't forget to add the formtastic CSS back in:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'formtastic', 'formtastic_changes' %>
```