# Disabling Simple Form classes from initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Expanding on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/plataformatec-simpleform/2eXfxboOQDg and [Rails: Using simple_form and integrating Twitter Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7198109/rails-using-simple-form-and-integrating-twitter-bootstrap) -- by default Simple Form will add `<action>_<model>` class names to all its forms.

I can disable that with `simple_form_for @thing, html: { class: nil }`, **but how do I move it into `config/initializers/simple_form.rb` to DRY things up?** I tried setting `config.default_form_class = nil` but to no avail.